# wxPython - wx.StaticText seems to interfere with wx.ComboBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to show two wx.StaticText objects together with a drop-down wx.ComboBox. If I only create the two wx.StaticText objects, I get the following result:

[image: First result]

But, if I also create the wx.ComboBox, I get this result:

[image]

The code including the creation of the wx.ComboBox is as follows:

```
class RegisterNewAppointmentFrameStep2( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent, firstName ):
    global cursor
    wx.Frame.__init__( self, parent = parent , id = -1, title = u'Marcação de consulta', size = ( 271, 138 ),
        style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ ( wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ) )
    #Centers this RegisterNewAppointmentFrameStep2:
    self.Center()
    #Creates panel as a child of this RegisterNewAppointmentFrameStep2:
    self.panel = wx.Panel( parent = self )
    #Query to determine all patients with the first name provided:
    results = cursor.execute( 'SELECT * FROM Paciente WHERE Primeiro_Nome = ( ? )', ( firstName, ) )
    results = results.fetchall()
    size = len( results )
    if size > 1: #size >= 2.
        self.instructionsLabel = wx.StaticText( self.panel, -1, '%d pacientes encontrados. Por favor selecione\nabaixo o sobrenome do paciente desejado.' % size,
            pos = ( 10, 10 ), size = ( 700, 200 ) )
        self.firstNameLabel = wx.StaticText( self.panel, -1, firstName, pos = ( 10, 50 ) )
        comboBoxValues = []
        for result in results:
            comboBoxValues.append( result[ 2 ] )
        self.dropDownList = wx.ComboBox( parent = self, id = -1, pos = ( 70, 50 ), size = ( 163, -1 ), choices = comboBoxValues, style = wx.CB_READONLY | wx.CB_SORT )
        boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        boxSizer.Add( self.instructionsLabel, 1, wx.EXPAND )
        boxSizer.Add( self.firstNameLabel, 1, wx.EXPAND )
        boxSizer.Add( self.dropDownList, 1, wx.EXPAND )
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The combobox parent should be self.panel instead of self.

Comment: Thanks, just changed that. Now the two wx.StaticText objects are appearing properly, but the wx.ComboBox is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the pos parameter for the StaticTexts and the ComboBox. That's the sizer's job to layout them properly. Now, I am not so sure about the size parameter, but I never use it because that too should be handled by the sizer. So try taking it out and see what it does.